# Indexing relational data correctly in Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to check that I am indexing my relational data correctly, as I am trying to wrap my head around Firebase. I have a two way relationship between users and addresses, both are one to one. The idea is that the user node is initially created with just their email, then when they add their address, a key for the addressID is added to the user node and simultaneously, a key for the userID is added to the address node. This is meant to be similar to how it is recommended in the "Structure Data" section of the Firebsae docs (at the bottom). However, to identify the address within the user node and to identify the user within the address node, I have used their auto generated key (i.e. address: userAutoID, user: addressAutoID; rather than userAutoID: true and addressAutoID: true; as the former is more descriptive and easier to understand. The use of an autogenerated ID as a key doesnt indicate what the key represents). The JSON structure is as follows (both nodes are children of the top-most node):

[image]

As you can see the address possesses the user's ID, and the user possesses the address ID. I feel as though the code I have used to achieve this is protracted and I could be going about this the wrong way. The code is triggered when the user has filled out a form for their address and they press submit. Hence, the User node exists before the address node. I use a for loop to sequentially obtain the key of each address that exists, which i then feed into another query, which then looks to find if the current user's ID exists whithin the current address node as the value of the userID key. If this is true, then I set the ID of the current address to the value of the addressID within the current users associated node. Here is the code:

```
self.rootRef.child("Addresses").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

for address in snapshot.children {

 guard let addressSnapshot = address as? FIRDataSnapshot else {

  print("failed to get addressSnapshot")

  return

 }

let addressSnapshotKey = addressSnapshot.key
self.rootRef.child("Addresses").child(addressSnapshotKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
 guard let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {

  print("error getting snapshotValue")

  return

 }

 let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

 if (snapshotValue["userID"] as! String) == userID {

  let correctKey = addressSnapshotKey

  let userRef = self.rootRef.child("Users").child(userID!)
  userRef.child("addressID").setValue(correctKey)

  }

 })

}
})
```

I can see that running two queries from one piece of code, may become expensive when the User and Addresses node become very large. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) PLEASE post your Firebase structure as text, not an image. That will alleviate us having to re-type in an answer. 2) Your question refers to indexing (i.e. Firebase indexes) but that's not really what you are asking. 3) The question states *the user node exists before the address node*, so why search the addresses for the user if the address node doesn't exist yet? Or are you trying to determine if the user already entered their address? Is there a reason you don't store the address information in the user node since it's 1-1? Can you clarify the question? (and fix the code formatting!)

Comment: Hi Jay, sorry for the mess, I've rearranged the code and next time I'll be sure to use text for my Firebase structure. The above code was situated within a button. When the button was pressed, the address object was set and then immediately after, the code above was executed from within the same button. After reading your advice, I have stored the address under the user node, I think I was just overthinking things. I really wish Firebase had done a better job of their iOS docs and provided more examples and workthroughs. As someone fairly new to programming, I have to say their docs are poor.

Comment: Keep in mind that because this is 1-1 the address info can be stored within the users node. However, when you need 1-many or many to many your original structure is the way to go - denormalizing your data is generally a good idea. The original Firebase docs were *much* better than the current ones and I agree they are fairly weak at this point.

Comment: Ok understood, thanks very much Jay!

Answer (score 0):

I would reuse the auto generated User key as the key under Addresses as well.

```
- Users
  - xyz (auto generated)
    - email: jo@jo.com

- Addresses
  - xyz (use the previously created id here too)
    - street
    - author
    - lat
    - lon
```

Comment: Hi @patrickmcd, thanks for the comment, this is what I have done, an image of my JSON is included. You will see that the userID of the Addresses node is the auto generated key of the user and the addressID of the Users node is the auto generated key of  the address

Comment: What I'm saying is don't auto generate the address key at all. Just use the same key that was generated when you created the user. Get rid of userID under Addresses and addressID under Users completely. They will automatically be linked because they'll share the same node under separate collections.

Comment: "they'll share the same node under separate collections". These are top level nodes, the only node currently above them is the root node. Are you saying that each entry (which consists of a Users and an Addresses) should involve an auto generated key, followed by the Users and Addresses nodes, which each contain an auto generated key?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say they'll share the same KEY under separate collections. When you create a user, you auto generate a key. But when you are ready to add an address, just use the same key. That's what I'm getting at in my example. You push to Users and xyz is the auto generated key. Now you know that key, so when you create an address, set it under xyz as well.